# Time and hours in java

Tags: java, time

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Nc3 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter time of arrival: ");
        double time = input.nextDouble();
        int arrivalTime;
        arrivalTime = 0;
        arrivalTime += time;

        if (time % 20 != 0) {
            time %= 20;
            time = 20 - time;
            System.out.println(arrivalTime +time);
        }

        else if (((arrivalTime + time) % 100) == 60.0) {
            time += 40;
            System.out.println(arrivalTime + time);
        }
        else
            System.out.println("Now - " +arrivalTime);

    }
}
```

I was asked to write a program that gets the input of the current time and give back the hour at which the next bus will leave knowing that a bus leaves every 20 minutes at 00, 20, 40 the problem is that if i input 2243 that represent 22:43 i will get back 2260 instead of 2300

Comment: first off, do not use double (floating  point) variable for this

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## *java.time*

I recommend you use [`java.time.Duration`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html) which is modelled on [ISO-8601 standards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) and was introduced with *Java-8* as part of [JSR-310 implementation](https://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/pfd/jsr310/JSR-310-guide.html).

**Demo:**

```
import java.time.Duration;
import java.time.LocalTime;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter time of arrival: ");
        showNextDepartureTime(input.nextLine());
    }

    static void showNextDepartureTime(String arrivalTime) {
        Duration nextDeparture = Duration.between(LocalTime.MIN, LocalTime.parse(arrivalTime));
        int remainder = nextDeparture.toMinutesPart() % 20;
        if (remainder != 0)
            nextDeparture = nextDeparture.minusMinutes(remainder).plusMinutes(20);

        System.out.printf("The next departure is at %2d:%02d", nextDeparture.toHoursPart(),
                nextDeparture.toMinutesPart());
    }
}
```

**A sample run:**

```
Enter time of arrival: 22:43
The next departure is at 23:00
```

**Another sample run:**

```
Enter time of arrival: 22:00
The next departure is at 22:00
```

#### Update

As suggested by Lino in his [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69417856/time-and-hours-in-java/69418112?noredirect=1#comment122698695_69418112), you can replace the `if` body as follows:

```
if (remainder != 0)
    nextDeparture = nextDeparture.plusMinutes(20 - remainder);
```

Comment: Note: you could also replace the `if` with: `nextDeparture = nextDeparture.plusMinutes(20 - remainder)`. I.e. just add the difference to "round" it up to the next multiple of twenty

Comment: Thanks, @Lino for the suggestion. The problem with your suggested solution is that it will not work when the minute is zero e.g. for `22:00`, it will give `22:20` as the output.

Comment: Ah yes, you're right, the `if` is required. So to correct my comment: only the body of the `if` *could* be replaced with what I've written earlier